# Adding Context Menu to sub view(Textview)of SimpleCursorAdapter onClick

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, android-contextmenu

I have created  listview with SimpleCursorAdapter each row contains multiple views(4 textview),I want to add context menu to one the textview on click.

I have added context menu to one of the textview but onclick of textview it always gives data of last row(data of textview of last row).

How can I fix this issue any help greatly appreciated.

**Below is my Code:**

In Below code  I am setting OnClick listener to textview when user click on text I register for context menu.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  address = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.host_address);
                     address = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.host_address);
                    address.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {                        
                            registerForContextMenu(address);
                            openContextMenu(address);
                            unregisterForContextMenu(address);
                        }
                    }); }
```

**Context Menu:**

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        menu.setHeaderTitle(address.getText());
        menu.add(0, OPEN_MAP, 0, "Open in maps");
        menu.add(0, COPY_ADDRESS, 1, "Copy");
    }
```

**Note:-**In the above code **address.getText()** always return last row address.

Comment: Please post the code related to the above functionality.

Comment: without nothing can happen!

Comment: @RameshR added code.

Comment: you are assigning text view to address inside getView() method,which contains the references to bottom most list item's text view since that is the last view which is laid out.

Comment: Ya your wright,but How could I fix this issue..Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

A [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) could be used as an [ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) or as standalone.
Standalone mode is that you do not set the [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) to act as your action bar, so you could use it as a simple view, put it wherever you want having the control of it.

In standalone mode, you need to manually populate the Toolbar with content/actions. For instance, if you want it to display actions, you need to inflate a menu into it

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blah);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);

    // Set an OnMenuItemClickListener to handle menu item clicks
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle the menu item
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.your_toolbar_menu);
}
```

Comment: This not what I was looking for,Please check my update.